# How to check whether or not the collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm search the function which return me bool value if collection is exist

Like this

```
value bool = database.**function**(string nameColeection)
```

please, tell me if this function exist and  what is name?

Comment: database.CollectionExists(nameColeection);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to query the namespace collection like so:

```
> db.system.namespaces.find()
{ "name" : "test.system.indexes" }
{ "name" : "test.another_test_collection" }
{ "name" : "test.another_test_collection.$_id_" }
{ "name" : "test.another_test_collection.$a_1_b_1_c_1" }

> db.system.namespaces.findOne({name: "mycollection"})
null
> db.system.namespaces.findOne({name: "test.another_test_collection"})
{ "name" : "test.another_test_collection" }
```

Note that this list also includes indexes. Currently there is no specific function to do this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1938